# why there is a deadlock in multithreaded program given below

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am new to multi threaded programming
What is the reason for dead lock in this approach if one Thread has to print odd numbers from 0 to 1000 and other has to print even numbers?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static int count1;
        static int count2;
        static Thread t1, t2;
        static void MulOf2()
        {
            while (count1 < 1000)
            {
                Console.Write("Th1" + (2 * count1) + "\n");
                count1++;
                if (t2.IsBackground)
                {
                    if (!t2.IsAlive)
                    {
                        t2.Resume();
                    }
                }
                t1.Suspend();
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            t1 = new Thread(MulOf2);
            t2 = new Thread(MulOf2Plus1);
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
        } 

         static void MulOf2Plus1()
        {
            while (count2 < 1000)
            {
                Console.Write("Th2" + ((2 * count2) + 1) + "\n");
                count2++;
                if (t1.IsBackground)
                {
                    if (!t1.IsAlive)
                    {
                        t1.Resume();
                    }
                }
                t2.Suspend();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the code to prevent crashes

Comment: Because e.g. each thread suspends the other at the same time. What exactly is surprising?

Comment: I can foresee a scenario where both threads manage to suspend each-other - a thread-race, but not impossible

Comment: I receive lots of `ThreadStateException`s because a thread is being resumed without being suspended before… If you want these processes to be synchronized, why use threads at all? You just add a huge overhead to it.

Comment: when I run it, it simply crashes, complaining that you can't resume a thread that wasn't user-suspended

Comment: There isn't any deadlock in the program, however you can suspend both threads. A deadlock occurs when the waiting process is still holding on to another resource that the first needs before it can finish.

Comment: Minor other issue. Since you're multiplying your counts by 2, you're not doing 0-1000, but 0-2000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you swallow enough exceptions to even get the code running, it can deadlock when the operations execute in the following order:

```
t2.Resume() //on t1
t1.Resume() //on t2
t2.Suspend() //on t2
t1.Suspend() //on t1
```

As a result both threads remain suspended.

This is generally not the way to handle thread synchronization. Personally, I have never had to use `Resume` or `Suspend` on threads.

You should read about synchronization mechanisms in .NET, starting with the `lock` statement. I recommend the [free chapters](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) from Albahari's [c# in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/):

Comment: Re your line about `Resume` / `Suspend`: and nor should you. Both are marked `[Obsolete]`

Comment: Also note that there is no exact alternate provided for `Resume` and `Suspend`. You need to use other synchronization primitives like `WaitHandle` etc

Comment: I have to use resume and suspend

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I believe that is intended, as non-cooperative cancellation will always end in tears.

Comment: @AbhinavKonda Why? Homework? Do you realize they are `Obsolete`?

Comment: @AbhinavKonda I assure you, you do not. Unless you are doing a homework assignment in which you are instructed to use them, in which case, show your professor Mr. Gravell's comment.

Comment: Nobody gave me this assignment, Its just for me to learn how to use `Resume` and `Suspand`

Comment: @AbhinavKonda If you want to learn how to use them, then learn **not** to use them. They are deprecated, so you shouldn’t use them, *ever*.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the situation Rotem already explained, you are using trying to use multithreading without allowing multithreading to happen. If you try to synchronize two threads in a way that they are exclusive to each other, only running one of them, then you are essentially throwing away all the benefits of using multithreading. Instead, you add a huge overhead in terms of thread management *and* synchronization. So your solution (if you get it working) is very likely to be much slower than a simple single-threaded implementation like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 1000; count++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Th2" + ((2 * count2) + 1));
    Console.WriteLine("Th1" + (2 * count1));
}
```

That being said, if you wanted to “repair” your solution in some way, then you would have to make sure that the `Suspend` and `Resume` operations are executed atomically, so that the other thread cannot execute between the instructions. You can do this by locking on an object during the execution.